# SIGABRT on cast to UIImage

Tags: ios, casting, uiimage

I'm using [FastttCamera](https://github.com/IFTTT/FastttCamera) as a wrapper to AVFoundation for taking, processing and displaying a picture. Here's my code (a FastttCamera delegate method) in which I cast (FastttCapturedImage *) to (UIImage *):

```
- (void)cameraController:(FastttCamera *)cameraController didFinishScalingCapturedImage:(FastttCapturedImage *)capturedImage
{
    //Use the captured image's data--note that the FastttCapturedImage is cast to a UIImage
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage *)capturedImage);

    //Save the image, and add the path to this transaction's picPath attribute
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory

    int timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

    NSString *timeTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",timestamp];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingString:timeTag]; //Add the file name
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file

    self.thisTransaction.picPath = filePath;

    [self.viewFinder setImage:(UIImage *)capturedImage];
}
```

However, I'm getting a SIGABRT at the line:

```
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage *)capturedImage);
```

with this console readout:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FastttCapturedImage CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e2a100'
```

I'm confused by the reference to CGImage. Is it a problem with my typecast? There was no complaint on build. Can someone please set me straight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs for `FastttCapturedImage`. It's not a `UIImage` so you can't just cast it like that. Use the provided property to get the `UIImage`.

Change the problematic line to:

```
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(capturedImage.fullImage);
```

You have the same problem later:

```
[self.viewFinder setImage:capturedImage.fullImage];
```

BTW - you didn't get a problem while compiling because a cast is a way to tell the compiler "trust me, it's really what I'm telling you it is". The problem here is you were wrong, it's not really what you claimed it was. :)

Comment: Thanks very much, @rmaddy! I was uneasy about that cast, but wasn't exactly sure why. I've still got a bit to do (the Image isn't appearing in the ImageView--instead, I'm still looking at the camera feed), but you really opened my eyes. Right now, I'm looking for a way to dismiss the camera feed. Also, I used the property `.scaledImage` instead of `.fullImage` since I don't need the full image for my purposes. Thanks again!